# Regex excluding words in certain sequence

Tags: r, regex, regex-negation

I would like to filter out certain fields, if they do not match criteria. The problem is their sequence. I tried following constructions:

```
(EXCLUDING)(?!\(MONDAY)(.*MONDAY).*
```

and

```
(EXCLUDING)(?!\()(.*MONDAY).*
```

What I want to achieve is to find a filter than catches `EXCLUDING * MONDAY` but not if there is a bracket between these words. That is, I want to catch:

```
EXCLUDING MONDAY
EXCLUDING WEDNESDAY AND MONDAY
EXCLUDING MONDAY AND WEDNESDAY
EXCLUDING MONDAY (WEDNESDAY IS OK)
```

but not

```
EXCLUDING WEDNESDAY (MONDAY IS OK)
```

The expressions above of course catch all of them. It is to be run in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?

```
mystrings <- c("EXCLUDING MONDAY",
"EXCLUDING WEDNESDAY AND MONDAY",
"EXCLUDING MONDAY AND WEDNESDAY",
"EXCLUDING MONDAY (WEDNESDAY IS OK)",
"EXCLUDING WEDNESDAY (MONDAY IS OK)")

grepl("EXCLUDING[^\\(]+MONDAY", mystrings)

> TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: perfect, no idea why i focused on the negative lookahead

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to match a pattern where `(` should not occur immediately before `MONDAY` you can use negative lookbehind assertion. Your regex was for negative lookahead, that's why it didn't work correctly for `(MONDAY`.

```
strs <- c("EXCLUDING MONDAY",
          "EXCLUDING WEDNESDAY AND MONDAY",
           "EXCLUDING MONDAY AND WEDNESDAY",
               "EXCLUDING MONDAY (WEDNESDAY IS OK)",
               "EXCLUDING WEDNESDAY (MONDAY IS OK)")

grepl("EXCLUDING.*(?<!\\()MONDAY", strs, perl=TRUE)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: thank you, i have to admit i have not tried the negative lookahead with < within R as when i entered it into the Regex online editor it claimed Java would not recognize it for some reason - as you could see for yourself http://regexr.com. I just assumed if Java did not, R is even more likely to reject